# Проблема со сборками и реферансами .net

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.416/NuGet.targets(282,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/tmp/builds/marketdal/Data/Data.csproj" was not found. [/tmp/builds/autocode_464926/TradeMarket.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.416/NuGet.targets(282,5): error MSB3202: The project file "/tmp/builds/marketbll/Business/Business.csproj" was not found. [/tmp/builds/autocode_464926/TradeMarket.sln]

Пытаюсь собрать сборку и проверить в автокоде но выдало ошибку
у меня есть три слоя PL DL BL
запихунл два слоя в третий и пишет что не видет их
как быть?

Answer (score 0):

У тебя ссылка на проект неправильная в файлах проектов и решения

> /marketdal/Data/Data.csproj" was not found.

Ты наверное сначала добавил существующий проект в решение, а потом перекинул файлы, ну или что-то типо того, если я правильно понял. ("/marketdal" - не нужно)

Просто в (.csproj) файлах проектов чекни ссылки и поправь их

Также в файле решения (.sln) тоже нужно подправить ссылки проектов